# Regex to pick out artist name and song title, issue with lazy matching

Tags: .net, regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to build a flexible regular expression to pick out the artist name and song title of a media file. I'd like it to be flexible and support all of the following:

01 Example Artist - Example Song.mp3

01 Example Song.mp3
(In this example, there's no artist so that group should be null)

Example Artist - Example Song.mp3

Example Song.mp3
(Again, no artist)

I've come up with the following (in .NET syntax, particularly for named capture groups):

```
\d{0,2}\s*(?<artist>[^-]*)?[\s-]*(?<songname>.*)(\.mp3|\.m4a)
```

This works well, but fails for this input:
01 Example Song.mp3

It swallows the song name as the artist, I believe because of greedy matching. So, I tried modifying the expression so that the artist part would be lazy matching:

```
\d{0,2}\s*(?<artist>[^-]*)*?[\s-]*(?<songname>.*)(\.mp3|\.m4a)
```

The change is:

```
(?<artist>[^-]*)?
```

became

```
(?<artist>[^-]*)*?
```

This does indeed fix the above problem. But now, it fails for this input:

01 Example Artist - Example Song.mp3

Now, it's too lazy in that it captures "Example Artist - Example Song" as the songname and captures nothing for the artist name.

Does anyone have a suggestion regarding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve this task only with greediness, you need to be more descriptive using groups (optional or not). An example:

```
(?x) # switch on comment mode
^    # start of the string
(?: (?<track>\d{1,3}) \s*[\s-]\s* )? # the track is optional ( including separators) 
(?: (?<artist>.+?) \s*-\s* )? # the same with the artist name
(?<title> .+ )
(?<ext> \.m(?:p3|4a) )
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/yS7pC9/1)

As an aside, audio filenames can be very weird, even with the best pattern of the world, I doubt you can handle all cases.

You can be a little more flexible and more efficient if you replace `.+` with something more explicit:

```
^(?x)
(?: (?<track>\d{1,3}) \s*[\s-]\s* )?
(?: (?<artist> \S+ (?>[ .-][^\s.-]*)*? ) \s*-\s*)?
(?<title> [^.\n]+ (?>\.[^.\n]*)*? )
(?<ext> \.m(?:p3|4a) )
```

*( `\n` are only here for test purpose, you can remove them when you apply the pattern one filename at a time)*

Comment: PS: I also didn't realize that you could have nested capture groups. They (along with the comments) make reading the regex much clearer. Thanks again.

Comment: Question: (Referencing the first regex above) I see that for artist, you do a lazy match (?<artist>.+?), with the question mark at the end. But for title, you omit the question mark which I believe means greedy match. This does work, but why? Why is it that the ext group is populated at all? Why doesn't title swallow ".mp3" instead of letting ext have it? I'd like to understand this better.

Comment: I think I answered my own question: The "ext" part is not optional, so it will be given priority for the purpose of satisfying the regex.

Comment: @BenjiFB: it is not because the ext part is not optional. The reason is that when you use a greedy quantifier `.+` for the "artist" group, the regex engine only needs 4 backtracking steps (the 4 characters of the extension, because `.+` takes all until the end), but if I use a non-greedy quantifier `.+?` instead, for each character, the regex engine must test if the following subpattern `\s*-\s*)?(?<title> .+)(?<ext> \.m(?:p3|4a))` fails until this subpattern succeeds. If you assume that most of the time the artist name is greater than 4 chars length, the greedy quantifier is a better choice.