# How to create logic for search bar music albums(band name and album name)?

Tags: swift, http, uisearchbar

Here is a problem. User enters artist name and album title in text field, presses Search button, then found artwork is shown in image view.
Artist name and album title in text field can be separated by next symbols: ‘-‘, ‘:’, ‘|’, ‘\’, ‘/‘, ‘~’
Examples: “Queen - Bohemian rhapsody”, “The Beatles : Abbey Road”. Also I have url, where I have to put band name and album name for request: theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/{APIKEY}/searchalbum.php?s={Artist name}&a={Album name}.

I have created search bar with function searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar).

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        let text = Array(searchBar.text!)
        var bandName = ""
        var albumName = ""
        var isBandName = true
        var isAlbumName = false
        var albumNameArray = [String]()
        for char in text {
            if char != " " && char != "-" && isBandName && !isAlbumName{
                bandName.append(char)
                continue
            }

            if char != " " && char != "-" && isAlbumName && !isBandName{
                albumName.append(char)
                continue
            }

            if (char == "-" || char == " ") && !isAlbumName && isBandName{
                isBandName = false
                isAlbumName = true
                continue
            }

            if char == " " && isAlbumName && !isBandName && albumName != ""{
                albumNameArray.append(albumName)
                albumName = ""
                continue
            }
            if text.firstIndex(of: char) == text.count - 1 {
                albumNameArray.append(albumName)
            }


        }

        requestToServer(band: bandName, album: albumName)
        print(bandName, albumNameArray)
    }

    func requestToServer(band: String, album: String?) {
        var urlString = "https://theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/searchalbum.php?s=\(band)"
        if let albumName = album {
            urlString += albumName
        }
                if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
                            guard let data = data else { return }
                            do {
                                print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
                            }catch let error {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }
                        task.resume()
                    }
    }
```

I want to realize search bar text field logic and create right url for http request.

Comment: You'd better use regex. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32288587/2142911

Comment: Thanks. I will try)